# Pointer to an 2D array increment in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    printf("%u ,%u\n",arr, &arr+1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the print statement: (Assuming integer size 4 bytes)
Let arr's memory location be 1000

**arr+1--gives 1016 (ie.next row memory)**

```
1000 1004 1008 1012 1016

1     2     3    4    5
```

**&arr+1 gives 1048**

I understood the logic but I can't understand that how the compiler identifies
**arr as 'pointer to an array of 4 integer'** and
**&arr as 'pointer to array of 3 arrays of 4 integer'**

**Even though both points to the same address (1000) before increment**

Comment: `arr` decays to the same type as `&arr[0]`, which is an array of 4 integers. `&arr` on the other hand is a pointer to array of 3 by 4 integers

Comment: `&arr` gives you a pointer to the array.  `arr` gives you a pointer to the array's first element.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is a 3-element array of 4-element array of `int`.

Arrays in expressions are automatically converted to pointers pointing at the first element of the array (some exception exists). Therefore `arr` is converted to a pointer pointing at its first element. The type of the first element is "a 4-element array of `int`, so `arr` is converted to "a pointer to a 4-element array of `int`" (`int(*)[4]`).

Operand of unary `&` (address) operator is one of the exceptions. `arr` is a 3-element array of 4-element array of `int`, so `&arr` is "a pointer to a 3-element array of 4-element array of `int`".

Note that the line

```
printf("%u ,%u\n",arr, &arr+1);
```

invokes *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type to `printf()`. `%u` expects `unsigned int`. You should cast the pointer to `void*` and use `%p` to print pointers like this:

```
printf("%p ,%p\n",(void*)arr, (void*)(&arr+1));
```

Alternatively, you can convert the pointers to integers (in an implementation-defined manner) and print them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    printf("%" PRIuPTR " ,%" PRIuPTR "\n",(uintptr_t)arr, (uintptr_t)(&arr+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays designates used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So the array `arr` declared like

```
int arr[3][4] = { /*...*/ };
```

is converted to pointer to its first element when it is used as an argument of a call of printf. The type of the array element is `int[4]`.  So a pointer to an object of this type has the type `int ( * )[4]`.

On the other hand the expression `&arr` has the type `int ( * )[3][4]`. Incrementing the pointer like `&arr + 1` yields the value that greater than the value of the expression `&arr`  by `sizeof( int[3][4] )` (that is equal to `12 * sizeof( int )`).

Pay attention to that you have to use the conversion specifier `%p` to output values of pointers.

```
printf("%p ,%p\n", (void * )arr, ( void * )( &arr+1 ) );
```